# Passing Variable With Apostrophe To SQL Query

Tags: excel, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2013, vba

I am using Excel to run paramaterized SQL Server Queries.  Everything works fine, except when the parameter has a apostrophe.  For example, let's say my syntax is this

```
Select * from testtable where arovaica = @passedvalue
```

And in Excel @passedvalue is set to `Michael's` I get an error of

> Incorrect syntax

How should I encapsulate this variable with an apostrophe in order for SQL to compile properly?

Comment: two apostrophes are required `''` or you could replace it with `+char(39)+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a replace as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440733/replace-single-quotes-in-sql-server)

```
    Select * from testtable where arovaica = REPLACE(@passedvalue, '', '''')
```

Comment: To my understanding replace will not work, as it seems that would remove the quote all together.  I think, judging from your comment, I just need to double the quote so SQL Server "sees" the string appropriately.

Comment: `Replace` should work but I've the got the apostrophes reversed `Select REPLACE('Michael''s', '', '''')`. Editing answer